# GridBagLayout: alignment and width when gridwidth is > 1

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

In this `JFrame` with a [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) with 4 columns, the brown line should be the limit between columns 1 and 2, and OK and Cancel buttons should be on each side of this limit:

[image]

The problems:

- OK + Cancel set is not centered with other buttons.
- Left and right `JTextArea` don't have the same width.

Column 1 seems to have a zero width when I was expecting columns 1 and 2 to be equal.

The code used:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class GblSO extends JFrame {

    // Instance variables
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    public GblSO() {
        // Set frame
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        // Text areas
        JTextArea left = new JTextArea("Left!");
        JTextArea right = new JTextArea("Right!");
        setConstraints(1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, null);
        addToFrame(left, 0, 1, 1, 5, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
        addToFrame(right, 3, 1, 1, 5, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

        // Transfer buttons
        JButton addBtn = new JButton(">");
        JButton rmvBtn = new JButton("<");
        setConstraints(0, 0, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(3, 5, 3, 5));
        addToFrame(addBtn, 1, 1, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
        addToFrame(rmvBtn, 1, 3, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

        // OK / Cancel buttons
        JButton okBtn = new JButton("OK");
        JButton canBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        setConstraints(0, 0, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(15, 4, 15, 4));
        addToFrame(okBtn, 0, 6, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST);
        addToFrame(canBtn, 2, 6, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST);

        // Show
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setConstraints(double weightx, double weighty, int fill, Insets insets) {
        gbc.weightx = weightx; // how much cell resizes
        gbc.weighty = weighty; // "
        gbc.fill = fill; // how component fills cell
        gbc.insets = (insets == null ? new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0) : insets);
    }

    private void addToFrame(Component comp,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, int anchor) {
        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
        gbc.anchor = anchor;
        add(comp, gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GblSO();

    }

}
```

For a test only: If I add the `>` and `<` buttons to the `JFrame` respectively in column 1 and 2, and don't span multiple columns, columns 1 and 2 are forced to have the same width and the bottom buttons set is now centered.

Code changed:

```
addToFrame(addBtn, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
addToFrame(rmvBtn, 2, 3, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
```

Result:

[image]

The two `JTextArea` have still a different width :-(, and obviously `>` and `<` are not going to be aligned!

How can I solve this problem so that buttons are centered, and the two `JTextArea` have the same width? Thanks by advance for your help.

(this code is inspired by this [tutorial](http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/Java/archives/0304/tabbone/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

That is because you don't have any components added on each column, which is somehow needed for `GridBagLayout` to work as one would expect.

A few remarks now:

Did you noticed in the tutorial you linked to, the <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons are aligned with the `JTextArea`, not the overall upper components?

When working with `GridBagLayout` it is better to instanciate a new `GridBagConstraint` for each component you're adding. It prevents you from forgetting to reset an attribute somewhere, which is difficult to troubleshoot.

Then, if you want your <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons to be center-aligned with your upper components, the easiest would be to create two `JPanel`: one with the upper components, the other one with your buttons. You can still use `GridBagLayout` for the upper panel and the default one (`FlowLayout`) for the buttons. You would put them into a `BorderLayout` position `CENTER` and `SOUTH` and you'd be good to go. Note that the *panels* would be center-aligned, not the space between the <kbd>OK</kbd> / <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons and the <kbd><</kbd> / <kbd>></kbd> buttons.

Back to the solution to your problem: you have to add "empty" components (`Container`, `JPanel`, emtpy `JLabel`, ...) on the first (or last) line with `weightx` set to `1.0` so the cells are actually filled in X direction, and `weighty` set to `0.0` so they are not visible in Y direction (and vice-versa if you want to use `gridheight` instead of `gridwidth`).

```
...
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

setConstraints(1, 0, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, null);
addToFrame(new Container(), 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
addToFrame(new Container(), 1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
addToFrame(new Container(), 2, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
addToFrame(new Container(), 3, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

// Text areas
...
```

That way the cells will exist and you'll get the expected result.

[image: Correct alignment]